# How do I turn off auto play

Tags: html, iframe, video, mp4, autoplay

I have a .mp4 video embedded in an iframe tag. I can't figure out how to turn off auto play. I tried everything: autoplay="false", autoplay="0", autoplay='false', autoplay='0' but nothing seems to work. Here's my code:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item behind" src='videos/cloud_computing.mp4' width='640' height='360' style='width:640px;height:360px;'></iframe>
</div>
```

Before this there was a YouTube video (that didn't auto play) and the code looked like this:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item behind" src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/v1uyQZNg2vE?enablejsapi=1&amp;html5=1&amp;hd=1&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;controls=1&amp;showinfo=0;rel=0;' width='640' height='360' style='width:640px;height:360px;'></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: iframes aren't media player tags. just because you can point the iframe at a video file doesn't magically turn `<iframe>` into `<video>`... Try `<iframe><video>...</video></iframe>` instead...

Comment: I actually tried using the video tag before. The problem is that the video is on top of a slideshow. Using the <video> tag makes the video disappear completely.

Comment: well, you can't turn an apple into an elephant. `<iframe>` has NO autoplay attribute, period. if the video hides behind the slideshow, then you should fiddle with the z-indices of both elements...

Comment: Yes you are right @MarcB. For now I uploaded the video to YouTube as I have a deadline. Later I will fiddle with my code. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

you need to put a `<video>` tag round it as it does not know the `iframe` is a video therefore `autoplay` will never work. Try the below code.

```
   <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item behind"> 
           <video src='videos/cloud_computing.mp4'
             width='640' height='360' style='width:640px;height:360px;' autoplay="0">
            </video>
        </iframe>
        </div>
```

> Note

i would use `autoplay="0"` and `autoplay="1"` as chrome does not recognise `autoplay="true"` or `autoplay="false"`.

Comment: I actually tried using the video tag before. The problem is that the video is on top of a slideshow. Using the <video> tag makes the video disappear completely.

Comment: if you can make a jsfiddle i would be happy to look into it. @maahd

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else works, then try adding

```
&autoStart=false
```

at the end of your src. If that doesn't work, then you might have to use a different medium in which to embed your video. Instead maybe use

```
<video>
   <source src="videos/cloud_computing.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and with some help from a friend we got a fix working. Check out the example here

```js
$('.play-btn').on('click', function () {
    // Fetch the video iframe
    var $video = $('.video');

    // Extract the src
    var src = $video.data('src');

    // Add a src attr which should start the video
    $video.attr('src', src);
});

$('.stop-btn').on('click', function () {
    $('.video').removeAttr('src');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe class="video" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DLzxrzFCyOs" type="mp4">
  </iframe>
<button class="play-btn" type="button">Play Video</button>
<button class="stop-btn" type="button">Stop Video</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BestByTest/2tfkhj04/

In this example the youtube video autoplay is set to off, some videos don't have this option, from what I have found and this was the fix. Can also be set to a modal, so the image opens the video. Be sure to set iframe to get the url after the modal is open. This way you won't have a video playing in a closed modal.